# Writing a setFormula() with a query formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good evening,
I have a formula in a cell:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1O9JBXnSpnigfVpMqNHq6nHcaHb7VwdroDgzDqfnD8iM";"'Tableau detail'!$b$3:$c");"select Col2 where (Col1='"&'Feuille 1'!$E$12&"')")
```

I would like to integrate it into a script with setformula ().
I tried with this writing:

`formuleNombre.setFormula('=query(IMPORTRANGE("1O9JBXnSpnigfVpMqNHq6nHcaHb7VwdroDgzDqfnD8iM";"'Tableau detail'!$b$3:$c");"select Col2 where (Col1='"&'Feuille 1'!$E$12&"')")');`

but it does not work :( I've this error :

> formula analysis error.

I tried this one too :

`formuleNombre.setFormula('=query(IMPORTRANGE("1O9JBXnSpnigfVpMqNHq6nHcaHb7VwdroDgzDqfnD8iM";"\'Tableau detail\'!$b$3:$c");"select Col2 where (Col1='"&\'Feuille 1\'!$E$12&"')")');`

and i've this error

> Sign) missing after the argument list. (line 56, file "Code")

Line 56 is the line where there is the formula above..... I do not see at all or where this error is.

Could you help me please.

Cordially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this error is because of the `' '`.

The formula you need to input in the `setFormula` must be a string, and what you give is:

```
'=query(
    IMPORTRANGE(
        "1O9JBXnSpnigfVpMqNHq6nHcaHb7VwdroDgzDqfnD8iM";
        "'Tableau detail'!$b$3:$c"
    );
    "select Col2 where (Col1='"&'Feuille 1'!$E$12&"')"
)'
```

You string is between single quotes, but you have single quotes in it.
You'll need to escape all the single quotes of the string, something like.

```
'=query(IMPORTRANGE("1O9JBXnSpnigfVpMqNHq6nHcaHb7VwdroDgzDqfnD8iM";"\'Tableau detail\'!$b$3:$c");"select Col2 where (Col1=\'"&\'Feuille 1\'!$E$12&"\')")'
```

Comment: Hello @liora Haydont
I thank you very much, the code works very well. I did not miss much ......
Anyway thank you for your help.
cordially.