# Using an apostrophe (') in a formula within a setFormula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following script that I receive the error

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 9, file "tracker.gs")

```
function tracker() {
  var spreadsheetIDs = ["myID1","myID2"];
  var i=0,sheet,thisID="";

  for (i=0;i<spreadsheetIDs.length;i+=1) {
    thisID=spreadsheetIDs[i];

    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisID).getSheetByName('History');
    sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(Login!G3=0,"",QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A1:AC4000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A4001:AC8000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A8001:AC12000")}),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 where Col2 ='"&Login!C2&"'",0))'); 
    
  };
};
```

I have identified that it is having the apostrophes around **'"&Login!C2&"'** that is causing the issues at the end of the formula, however this is a crucial criteria in the QUERY function.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape them by prepending a `\` or use template literal instead of a literal string

Replace

`sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(Login!G3=0,"",QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A1:AC4000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A4001:AC8000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A8001:AC12000")}),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 where Col2 ='"&Login!C2&"'",0))');`

by

`sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(Login!G3=0,"",QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A1:AC4000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A4001:AC8000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A8001:AC12000")}),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 where Col2 =\'"&Login!C2&"\'",0))');`

or

`` sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=IF(Login!G3=0,"",QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A1:AC4000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A4001:AC8000");IMPORTRANGE(Core!B1,"History!A8001:AC12000")}),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 where Col2 ='"&Login!C2&"'",0))`); ``

Related

- [Writing a setFormula() with a query formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49158072/1595451)
- [Why would setFormula() turn a working formula into one with #REF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54614188/1595451)